# Optional that test if a value is not null AND not empty

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to use an optional for the following result:  if a value (string) is null or empty return "TOTO" else return the value.

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
String s = null;
```

Simple approach without `Optional`:

```
if(s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
  return "TOTO";
}
```

Wrapping with `Optional`:

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(s) // will filter the value if it is null
  .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty()) // will filter the value if it is empty
  .orElse("TOTO"); // default value if Optional is empty
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes I want to do it with Optional, but when str is null, it does not work

Comment: What does not work? The example code returns `"TOTO"` if the provided String is `null`

Comment: Sorry, it works, my apologies

Comment: Or just `return ( s == null || s.isEmpty() )  ? "TOTO" : s;`